# INSERT or UPDATE from another table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, with same schema -

```
create table test1 (
a INT NOT NULL ,
b INT NOT NULL ,
c INT,
PRIMARY KEY (a,b)
);

create table test2 (
a INT NOT NULL ,
b INT NOT NULL ,
c INT,
PRIMARY KEY (a,b)
);
```

I want to insert values from test2 table into test1, but if the row with same primary key already exist, update it. I know in mysql you can do similar thing with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE like -

```
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES (1,2,3)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=3;
```

But I dont know how to do the above query with a SELECT from another table. What I am looking for is a query of form -

```
INSERT INTO test2 
SELECT a, b, c FROM test1
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c = c + t.c 
(Select a, b, c from tests1)t;
```

This query is obviously invalid. I would appreciate if somebody can make a valid query out of it.

Comment: maybe you mean `INSERT INTO test2` or ?

Comment: I would run two querys, one for update and one for insert...

Comment: @echo_Me yeah test2, corrected. Thanks.

Comment: what you mean by t.c ?

Comment: @ericpap But then how would you know when to update ? Do you mean something like an if/ else where I first select the row from test2 with values from test1. It there are no rows then I insert otherwise update. I could do that, thanks, hoping for a simpler solution though.

Comment: @echo_Me I basically want to add the c column from test1 table to c column of test2 table if (a,b) columns are same. And if there are no rows with (a,b) in test2 then insert a row with a,b,c from test1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
INSERT INTO test2 
SELECT a, b, c as c1 FROM test1
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c = c + c1
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do it with this SQL:

```
INSERT INTO test1 (a, b, c) 
    SELECT t.a as a, t.b as b, t.c AS c FROM test2 AS t
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=t.c;
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends, I use the PK autoincrement feature, for Row Unique identifier, I split a big table, so the small one have changes I can't miss, I read several opinions, even merge and remake PK that's do not work for me. The result set in Memory looks like if you don't mention the full columns name you will have errors. I did this and work, I hope some body have a better and smaller solutions:

```
>INSERT
>INTO    t_traffic_all 
>SELECT  
>t_traffic.file_id,
>t_traffic.cust,
>t_traffic.supp,
>.
>. (a lot...)
>.
>t_traffic.i_traffic_type,
>t_traffic.date_posted,
>t_traffic.date_update
>FROM    t_traffic 
>ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
>t_traffic_all.file_id =    t_traffic.file_id,
>t_traffic_all.cust =   t_traffic.cust,
>t_traffic_all.supp =   t_traffic.supp,
>t_traffic_all.imprt =  t_traffic.imprt,
>.
>.
>.
>t_traffic_all.i_traffic_type=  t_traffic.i_traffic_type,
>t_traffic_all.date_posted= t_traffic.date_posted,
>t_traffic_all.date_update= t_traffic.date_update
> Affected rows: 11128
> Time: 29.085s
```

the total rows processed where 18608, so it insert 11128 and update 7480 (7554 should be)  this numbers do not are very precise but the result was.